# The word "muddle" should use active or passive?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

When I couldn't distinguish two object clearly I would say:

> 1. "I got muddled A up with B." or
> 2. "I muddled A up with B."

I found similar expression in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115569/when-you-cannot-recognize-identical-twins/115575), and it seems both expression are correct. But I'm not sure which expression sounds more natural.

Comment: Do you mean **mix**?

Comment: **A and B got muddled up by me.** or **I muddled up A and B.**

Answer (score 2):

You could use either of these formations:

> I got A muddled up with B.
>
> I muddled up A and B.
>
> I got A and B muddled up.

Note that the conjugation that you use with muddled up is not always `with`.